# SetWindowPos failing to bring windows to front in Windows 8 when Windows 8 apps are running

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, window-position

I have a chat application written in VB.net. It uses SetWindowPos function to set the window to top when a new chat message is received. It works fine also.But in windows 8 it will not bring the window to front when windows 8 apps like reader or photo is running.These apps will be running with full screen mode in Windows 8. So my chat application windows is not appearing at the top when popup occurs. So how can i make it to appear even when these windows 8 apps are running in full screen mode.

Comment: Desktop applications are not allowed to jump in front of Windows Store applications and vice versa. You can [raise a toast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864353/use-windows-8-toast-notification-from-desktop-app) if you want to get the user's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Applications with 'UIAccess' are allowed to display on top of the full screen apps. Look at the answer to [Windows 8 Layered Windows Over Metro Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232450/windows-8-layered-windows-over-metro-apps). This question is about layered windows, but that makes no difference. Eric's problem was the same as yours, that his window was not displaying on top of the Metro interface.

In short, you need to:

1. Declare uiAccess="true" in your application's manifest
2. Your executable needs to be digitally signed with a trusted certificate.
3. Your application needs to be installed in a trusted location, i.e. Program Files

Comment: Note that this is not what the UIAccess feature is intended for. It is intended for assistive technology tools.