# Set foreground window on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dllimport, user32

I've read about a few ways to force a window to be displayed on the foreground with C#, making use of Win32's user32.dll.

- [How do I bring an unmanaged application window to front, and make it the active window for (simulated) user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228089/how-do-i-bring-an-unmanaged-application-window-to-front-and-make-it-the-active)
- https://shlomio.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/solved-setforegroundwindow-win32-api-not-always-works/

These work perfectly, except for one situation.
On Windows 8, if either the Start Menu or a Windows Store App is on the foreground, these will fail.

I only need to make this work when the Start Menu is on the foreground though.
Is there an hidden way to accomplish this?

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe you can get this done with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx. The problem is that the search window is already topmost so you need to get the handle of that window and change it zOrder and then use the same function to set your window to be topmost too.

Comment: Didn't try it myself, but i ran into some reports that it doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850230/setwindowpos-failing-to-bring-windows-to-front-in-windows-8-when-windows-8-apps

Comment: I can't try it either as I haven't windows 8, but what you need to understand is that all windows 8 windows are in the end build using the GDI they have normal handles and you can use the Win32 functions as before, so I believe it is worth you trying.

Answer (score 2):

```
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>
            {
                try
                {  
                    if (!this.IsActive)
                    {
                        //pressing windows button
                        InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(1000);

                    ApplicationRunningHelper.GetCurrentProcessOnFocus();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                 ...
                }
            });

 public static class ApplicationRunningHelper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass 
        // IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        /// The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the 
        /// foreground window.
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(HandleRef hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);

        //one source
        private static int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private static int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private static int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private static int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private static int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        private static int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        private static int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;

        //other source
        private static int SW_SHOW = 5;

        /// <summary>
        /// check if current process already running. if runnung, set focus to 
        /// existing process and returns true otherwise returns false.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool GetCurrentProcessOnFocus()
        {
            try
            {
                Process me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                Process[] arrProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(me.ProcessName);
                IntPtr hWnd = arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
                ForceForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static void ForceForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            uint foreThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            uint appThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
            const uint SW_SHOW = 5;

            if (foreThread != appThread)
            {
                AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, true);
                BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
                AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, false);
            }
            else
            {
                BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
            }
        }
    }
```