# The form fails to popup in windows 8

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-8, popup

I have a chat application written in VB.net which is used to chat between users who are connected in LAN inside a office . The application popups whenever user gets new chat message. It works fine in windows XP. But sometimes in windows 8 the application fails to popup the chat window. So my chat window is not appearing at the top when popup occurs for new messages.

I have tried using  setwindowspos,  form.Show(), form.BringToFront() which can bring the form to topmost. But sometimes this will not work properly.
So is there any other method other than those three(which i have mentioned above) i have used which can make the form popup and bring it to front.

Comment: Do you get an exception or is there anything else that can explain the behaviour?

Comment: You havent provide any additional information. Should your question be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WinForms app is a desktop application, so it's likely that the reason the pop-up is not being displayed in Windows 8 is because the desktop is not visible.

Remember that Windows 8 brings with it a whole new Start Screen interface and relegates the desktop to [an alternate mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/desktop). All desktop applications still run, but they run in this separate mode and cannot interact with the new Metro applications (or whatever they're calling them nowadays). Yes, it's too bad that the usability folks at Microsoft [didn't listen to Larry Tesler and have decided instead to mode us in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(computer_interface)), but *c'est la vie*.

So anyway, the pop-up is still being displayed, but it's being displayed on the desktop, which is not visible. Bringing it to the top isn't doing any good because it's already at the top of all the other windows on the desktop. If you click on the "Desktop" tile in the Start Screen, you should see your window.

Fixing this problem is going to take some work. Forcing a focus switch to the desktop mode is a horrible idea from a usability perspective, and I'm not sure it's even possible. A better solution would be to look into using [Toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx) instead, which [can be done from a desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864353/use-windows-8-toast-notification-from-desktop-app).